# MySQL performance with large number of records - partitioning?

Tags: mysql, performance, database-partitioning, large-data

I am trying to build a database that would contain a large number of records, each with a lot of columns(fields) - maybe around 200-300 fields total for all tables. Let's say that I would have in a few years about 40.000.000 to 60.000.000 records.

I plan to normalize the database, so I will have a lot of tables (about 30-40) -> and lots of joins for queries.
Database will be strictly related to US, meaning that queries will be based on the 50 states alone (if a query is made, it won't allow to search/insert/etc in multiple states, but just one).

What can I do to have better performance?

Someone came with the idea to have all the states in different table structures, meaning I will have 50 tables * the 30-40 for the data (about 200 tables)! Should I even consider this type of approach?

The next idea was to use partitioning based on the US 50 states. How about this?

Any other way?

Comment: Use partitioning, think again about 200 fields in table, it definitely should be normalized.

Comment: @rMX, I read that as 200-300 columns over 30-40 tables, so 5-10 columns per table on average.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The best optimization is determined by the queries you run, not by your tables' structure.**

If you want to use partitioning, [this *can be* a great optimization](http://www.slideshare.net/PerconaPerformance/boost-performance-with-my-s-q-l-51-partitions), if the partitioning scheme supports the queries you need to optimize.  For instance, you could partition by US state, and that would help queries against data for a specific state.  MySQL supports "partition pruning" so that the query would only run against the specific partition -- but only if your query mentions a specific value for the column you used as the partition key.

You can always check whether partition pruning is effective by using EXPLAIN PARTITIONS:

```
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS
SELECT ... FROM MyTable WHERE state = 'NY';
```

That should report that the query uses a single partition.

Whereas if you need to run queries by date for example, then the partitioning wouldn't help; MySQL would have to repeat the query against all 50 partitions.

```
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS
SELECT ... FROM MyTable WHERE date > '2013-05-01';
```

That would list all partitions.  There's a bit of overhead to query all partitions, so if this is your typical query, you should probably use range partitioning by date.

*So choose your partition key with the queries in mind.*

Any other optimization technique follows a similar pattern -- it helps some queries, possibly to the disadvantage of other queries.  So be sure you know *which* queries you need to optimize for, before you decide on the optimization method.

---

Re your comment:

Certainly there are many databases that have 40 million rows or more, but have good performance.  They use different methods, including (in no particular order):

- [Indexing](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really)
- [Partitioning](http://www.slideshare.net/PerconaPerformance/boost-performance-with-my-s-q-l-51-partitions)
- [Caching](http://memcached.org/)
- [Tuning MySQL configuration variables](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/29/what-to-tune-in-mysql-server-after-installation/)
- [Archiving](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-archiver.html)
- Increasing hardware capacity (e.g. more RAM, solid state drives, RAID)

My point above is that **you can't choose the best optimization method until you know the queries you need to optimize.**  Furthermore, the best choice may be different for different queries, and may even change over time as data or traffic grows.  Optimization is a continual process, because you won't know where your bottlenecks are until after you see how your data grows and the query traffic your database receives.

Comment: What would happen if I don't use partitions at all? Leaving the tables as they are for 40 millions records would be a performance mess? Can you give me some other ideas on how to properly design for performance?

Comment: 40 million records is not very big. If each is (say) 100 bytes, that's only 4GB which could easily fit in main memory and be accessed quickly.